# Using IISHandler to stream a radio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to stream my own online radio on my site. I'm right now focusing on simply using an http handler and html5 to do so.

How can I keep IISHandler constantly running without ever ending for each user? Like a real online radio.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, you should ask them separately, showing the relevant code for each.

Comment: Only have 1 question now.

Answer (score 0):

You have directly `redirect` to any url inside `handler` provided that url has `audio` content, you are are intended to put `handler` to `<audio>` src. So you can try this.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //context.Response.Redirect("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/148976759/stream?client_id=201b55a1a16e7c0a122d112590b32e4a");
    // you can use above or else below
    byte[] content = null;
    string fileName = context.Server.MapPath(@"\mp3\") + context.Request["file_name"];

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            content = new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length)];
            stream.Read(content, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
            context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

`<audio src="Handler1.ashx" controls></audio>`

Regarding `IISHandler constantly running?` -- When you host this in IIS, any request to handler ( i.e. you will have a `html` page having audio's src= `handler`, so end-user hits that html page, handler will be invoked), it will process the request. The similar concept like `aspx` . They are hosted in IIS, any request to that will be process. Do you get my point here?

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. But how will I be able to play another sound cloud track since I redirected the url?

Comment: For that, you need pass something (as querystring to handler), and in handler get that value/parameter, and then based on param redirect to concerned url. If you need help on that, i can repost my code.

Comment: I see. Since not all the audio will be from soundcloud, is it possible to Stream to my SQL server?

Comment: Yes, if you have audio blob data in SQL Server, then you just need to set conent type and write audio, or if you have audio file path in SQL, then read content and write to Response. I have updated code for this, you can check it out.